# How can I use a letter to select from a multiple choice list?

Tags: python-2.7, input, while-loop

I'm new to programming as a whole and in my journey to understand it, Python specifically, I am attempting to recreate The Camel Game. The steps I have followed thus far instruct me to create a while loop that will keep looping while a variable done = False. Inside the loop I am instructed to print several choices, selected by a letter, that will eventually do different things. Currently I am attempting to quit the program by selecting option Q, yet I get an error every time I type Q and then enter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/wasteland_Game.py", line 15, in <module>
    user_Choice = input("You decide to: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Q' is not defined
```

However, if I type "Q" including the quotation marks, the program ends. Onto my question: How do I get only the letter without quotation marks to work as the letter with quotation marks does?

Also this is my first time posting a question here, please excuse any formatting issues.

Thank you in advance,

RavusFlapjack

Python Version 2.7.9

```
print("Welcome to Wasteland!")
print("You escaped with a Pristine Deathclaw Egg and need to get to Diamond City!")
print("The Deathclaws want their egg back and are chasing you down!")
print("Survive your Wasteland Trek and outrun the Deathclaws!\n")

done = False

while not done:
    print("A. Drink from your trusty canteen.")
    print("B. Move ahead walking speed.")
    print("C. Move ahead full spring.")
    print("D. Stop and rest.")
    print("E. Check your Pip-Boy for status.")
    print("Q. Quit")
    user_Choice = input("You decide to: ")
    if user_Choice == "Q":
        print("Nobody likes a quitter!")
        done = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.  This will still read a line, and the user must press enter.

According to Python 2.7 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) on `input()`:

> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

The basic idea is that `input()` reads a string, then evaluates it (as if it were entered from an interactive shell).  It's looking for the symbol (variable, etc.) named `Q` which doesn't exist, generating an error.  You just want the string itself, not the string evaluated.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that fixed the issue straight away!